# Python function is not running

Tags: python

After about 5 years of not using Python I decided to get back into it. I started recoding my Discord bot in Python from NodeJS and it was doing alright but then I started getting this strange bug.

My problem is quite simple. I have two files: `__main__.py` and `commander.py`

**main**.py

```
from core.utility import parser, discord
from core.admin import commander

def ping(arguments, flags, options):
    print("PONG")

commander.addCommand("ping", "A ping pong request.", None, None, ping)
print('a')
```

commander.py

```
list = []

def addCommand(name, description, usage, permissions, callback):
    command = {}
    command["name"] = name
    command["description"] = description
    command["usage"] = usage
    command["permissions"] = permissions
    command["callback"] = callback
    print("Command added: ", name)
    list.append(command)
```

When I call `commander.addCommand` inside of `__main__.py` the print statment doesn't print. I also noticed that `print('a')` is also not printing which lead me to believe that the application is being block by the Discord library I am using, which is [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py).

Also noticed that when I press ctrl + c to stop the process in Putty the print statement within `commander.addCommand` actually print so I am almost certain the application is being block but I don't know how to run it as async.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Color me clueless, but what module is `core` from?

Comment: A module made by me. It is in the same directory as `__main__.py`

Answer (score 0):

This should really be a comment but I can't do that yet. Is your indentation in `commander.py` correct? Everything after `def addCommand(...)` should be indented. Unless you just wrote it wrong in your question.

Edit: I failed to reproduce this error. It runs on my machine just fine. Instead of importing discord from your own file, why not get it from pip? That's probably the only difference between your scripts and mine.

Comment: Could you fix the indentation in your question please?

Comment: Edited and fixed.

Comment: The reason your code work fine because you're not using the Discord library and creating the actual application part that block the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with Putty. Your code actually does not call into `discord` at all. It is possible that your stdout buffer is not being flushed. Try one of these two approaches.

Use `-u` argument in python

```
python -u __main__.py
```

Add flushes after print statements

```
print('Whatever')
import sys; sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Nope, nothing get printed. As I stated I almost 100% sure this is a blocking problem.